# How can I deal with invalid IDs in before_filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

Let's say my controller looks like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_user,:only => [:index,:create,:update,:destroy]
  def index
     @some_objects = @user.objects.all
  end

  ...

  private
  def find_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

end
```

If the `user_id` param does not exist, @user will be nil.I think this is not the way:

```
def index
   if @user
      @some_objects = @user.objects.all
   else
      # ?
   end
end
```

The code would look uglier having all these checks in my controller ... not to mention I'd have to duplicate a lot of the logic if other controllers are similar to this one.
How do you deal with these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `user_id` param does not exist, then `find` method throw `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception. This exception is caught in a before_filter and rendered error. Аll subsequent filters and the `index` action will not be called.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_user,:only => [:index,:create,:update,:destroy]
  def index
     @some_objects = @user.objects.all
  end

  private
  def find_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    # render or redirect_to error
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be placed in the same filter:

```
private
def find_user
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
  redirect_to where_you_want_to_go_when_no_user_url unless @user #for example login page
end
```

If you want to render your controller actions even without a @user and you always need the @some_objects (and you don't want the variable to be null), you can have another before_filter:

```
def get_some_objects
  @some_objects = @user.present? ? @user.objects.all : []
end
```

or combining both options (redirect or set some_objects variable):

```
def set_variables
  @user = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
  if @user
    @some_objects = @user.objects.all
  else
    redirect_to where_you_want_to_go_when_no_user_url
  end
end
```

I hope this helps.

EDIT: change 'find' to 'find_by_id' to avoid errors, when id is null or user for given id does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make it perfectly dry is to use a dedicated gem: [inherited_resources](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/230-inherited-resources)

It will basically handle everything for you, preloading as expected your resources according to the context.

Of course you can add your desired specific scopes, see tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask for a specific id and AR can't find it, it throws a RecordNotFound error. 
You would have to catch that with something like:

```
irb(main):025:0> begin
irb(main):026:1* Location.find 100
irb(main):027:1> rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
irb(main):028:1> puts "Oops: #{e.message}"
irb(main):029:1> end
Oops: Couldn't find Location with ID=100
=> nil
```

If you are wanting to apply something to all controllers you should probably think about adding your method to ApplicationController...

Comment: You can always use 'find_by_id' instead of 'find' - it returns nil when record is not found.

Comment: Clever! I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!